# Kivy update label dynamically on canvas

Tags: python, label, kivy

I am trying update Label on canvas , but it changed only if I call update() method from MyApp(APP).

And what is interesting that method obj Slider (on touch) works perfectly

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
 from kivy.core.window import Window
 from kivy.uix.label import Label
 from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
 from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
 from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
 from kivy.graphics import (Color, Ellipse)
 from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
 import random
 from functools import partial

 class Canvas_w(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.i = 0
        super(Canvas_w, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label_text =Label(text= "0",color = (255,0,0))

    def update_text(self, text):
        self.label_text.text = text

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            d=30
            self.i+=1
            Color(1., 0, 0)
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d/2, touch.y - d/2), size=(20,20))
            self.label_text=str(self.i)

class Label_l(GridLayout):
     bones = 0
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(Label_l, self).__init__(**kwargs)
         self.label_text =Label(text= "0")
         self.add_widget(self.label_text)
         #self.label_text.text=self.C.i
     def update_text(self, text):
         Label_l.bones=text
         self.label_text.text = str(Label_l().bones)#
         Label_l.text=str(Label_l().bones)

class WidgetContainer(GridLayout):
    sld_value = 0.00001
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(WidgetContainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
         self.cols = 1
         self.speedControl = Slider(min=0.00001, max=3, step=0.0001)
         self.add_widget(Label(text="Speed Iteration"))
         self.add_widget(self.speedControl)
         self.add_widget(Label(text=''))
         self.speedValue = Label(text="0.00001")
         self.add_widget(self.speedValue)
         self.speedControl.bind(value=self.on_value)
    def on_value(self, instance, speed):
         self.sld_value = speed
         WidgetContainer.sld_value = self.sld_value

         self.speedValue.text = str(round(speed,5))
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
         b3 = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")
         b1 = FloatLayout()
         self.painter = Canvas_w()
         self.label_l= Label_l()
         b1.add_widget(self.label_l)
         b1.add_widget(self.painter)
         b1.add_widget(WidgetContainer())
         b3.add_widget(b1)
         return(b3)
if __name__=="__main__":
     MyApp().run()
```

I am trying update Label on canvas , but it changed only if I call update() method from MyApp(APP).

And what is interesting that method obj Slider (on touch) works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code:

- The `color` attribute of a `Label` requires a list of four values with each value in the range 0 to 1. Change `self.label_text =Label(text= "0",color = (255,0,0))` to `self.label_text =Label(text= "0",color = (1,0,0,1))` in the `Canvas_w` class.
- The above `Label` is never getting drawn. You need to add `self.add_widget(self.label_text)` to the `__init__()` method of `Canvas_w`.
- You have another `Label` in the `Label_l` class that is being drawn on top of the `Label` in the `Canvas_w`.

After fixing the above problems, I believe your code will work as you expect.

If you call `self.canvas.clear()`, it appears as though the `label_text` child of `Canvas_w` is removed. Actually it is not removed, but is just not visible (perhaps overdrawn). One way to make it visible is to just make sure it is drawn last by removing it and then re-adding it (last added child is drawn last), like this:

```
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.remove_widget(self.label_text)
        self.add_widget(self.label_text)
```

After a bit more research, I believe that the `canvas.clear()` is removing the drawing of the `Label` from the `Canvas`. You can, however, do your drawing on `canvas.before` by using:

```
with self.canvas.before:
```

in the `on_touch_down()` method. And rather than using:

```
self.canvas.clear()
```

use:

```
self.canvas.before.clear()
```

I believe that your `Label` will be displayed correctly after doing the above.

Comment: John Anderson, you saved my life! Thank you very much! Color and self.add_widget(self.label_text) worked, but after super should put!

Comment: But there is poblem, when I Clear canvas (canvas.clear()) this label dissapeared! may be you know how load label again?

Comment: That is odd, and I don't claim to understand why that would happen, but I have added a way to work around it in my answer above.

Comment: I have added a suggestion to use `canvas.before`.